# (php) URL rewriting and 500 internal server error

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am having problems with this .htaccess that fires a `500 internal server error`, the regex works as expected on regex101.com but here not.

Current URL: http://urlsite.com or http://urlsite.com?id=ID with optional &code=CODE

Desider URL: http://urlsite.com or http://urlsite.com/firstname-lastname-id with optional ?code=CODE

**.htaccess**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[\w-]+-([\w\d]+)\/*[?code=]*(\w*)$ http://localhost:8080/ index.php?id=$1&code=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: There are errors every where. First thing is to clearly explain what URLs are you trying to rewrite and what are your target URLs.

Comment: Remove space before index.php at the last line.

Comment: @anubhava I have already written the URLs current and desider in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of revo!

The error was the space before the "index.php" at the last line.

Thank you again :)